# Bootstrap row not centering items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am using Bootstrap 5 row property to make my website responsive. However, when I try to add 2 divs next to each other, they don't seem to align at the very center of the webpage, instead, there is quite an unused gap at the right that I can't get rid of. For this section I am using class="container". [image]Any tips? Code below. I also added an image of how it looks when I inspect.

```
<h1> (SPH) </h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="box col-lg-6">
                        <h3> Who We Are </h3>
                        <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus fuga repellendus minima maiores beatae unde odit eius in sint optio. Ipsum optio neque beatae quod necessitatibus dolor iste quae voluptatibus. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box col-lg-6">
                        <h3> What We Do </h3>
                        <p> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam saepe illum dolores corporis suscipit enim at non temporibus perspiciatis corrupti dicta pariatur, veritatis beatae error doloremque voluptates. Eius, eveniet accusantium. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Probably you miss .container div From docs: `Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are required when using our default grid system. `

Comment: Bootstrap 5 or 4, you tag is 4 not 5

Comment: Add `justify-content-center` as a class to a parent element such as a container or the row itself.

Comment: I have a container class in the section tag. I added the justify-content-center and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments.

You can use a class at the top of your page like : **container**.

**Example:**

```
<div class= container justify-content-center> /your code here/ </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer has a few semantic issues so I'd figured I post one. Essentially, you should nest your `Bootstrap row` into a container. Then you can add `justify-content-center` on the row because it has a `display: flex;` by default.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center"> (SPH) </h1>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="box col-lg-6">
      <h3> Who We Are </h3>
      <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus fuga repellendus minima maiores beatae unde odit eius in sint optio. Ipsum optio neque beatae quod necessitatibus dolor iste quae voluptatibus. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box col-lg-6">
      <h3> What We Do </h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam saepe illum dolores corporis suscipit enim at non temporibus perspiciatis corrupti dicta pariatur, veritatis beatae error doloremque voluptates. Eius, eveniet accusantium. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very good example, also works and I think I'll stick to this one. But as a question, I am structuring this page in sections, so I added the class="container" in the opening section tag, but should I keep doing this or use another div just like in your example?

Comment: That's a good question, and really it won't affect the code if you use a div or a section with the `container`. However, personally, I like to use`wrappers` and `containers` with divs, and typically the class or `id` I give the section sort of describes what the section is about. For example, you could have section one be "home", section two be "contact" with the corresponding `id's`

Comment: @adrman47 you can also take a look at some [CSS Naming Conventions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849/) that help with naming classes, it especially helps when other languages start to get involved.